# Width is not taken right inside a div

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/w2P7s/

```
<div id="a">aaa</div>
<div id="b">
    <div id="col1">col1</div>
    <div id="col2">col2</div>
</div>
#a
{
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: red;
}

#b
{
    background-color: green;
}

#col1
{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
}

#col2
{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

col1 and col2 must be inside "b" but it looks like it overflows

Comment: Your fiddle goes [here..](http://jsfiddle.net/w2P7s/4/)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a floating `<div>` you can set `overflow:hidden` for it's neighbour. It will float next to the div and take up the rest of the available width. If you do this twice (One inside another), you'll get the result I think you're looking for:

Give `#b` the style `overflow:hidden`:

```
#a
{
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: red;
}

#b
{
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: green;
}

#col1
{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
}

#col2
{
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/w2P7s/11/)

Comment: Can you explain the logic? - @oGeez

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a float issue rather than a width issue. Since you have everything floating left, they're all removed from the flow and stacked next to each other, even though #col1 and #col2 have a different wrapper.

Try adding `clear:left;` to #b. This will force it to appear below any previous elements that are floated to the left.

http://jsfiddle.net/nathanlong/byRDq/

Explanation of the clear property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear

Answer (score 0):

we can do it 2 ways

remove `float: left;` from #a

OR

Use `clear:both;` in #b

I think u are looking for this???

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
#a
{

    width: 30%;
    background-color: red;
}

#b
{
    background-color: green;
}

#col1
{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
}

#col2
{
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

**Regards

Ali Muhammad**